# Element to use in place of carbon for a creature using liquid methane

Tags: science-based

So I have this rogue planet with a large moon who's pull keeps the planet's mantle active. The plants here rely on geothermal energy. Even with all the geothermal energy coming up, it is still very cold.
So this world's inhabitants use liquid methane instead of water.

What are some feasible options for the element creatures here use instead of  carbon? Or would carbon still work at the temperature methane is liquid?

Comment: Welcome! Please take a moment to check out our [tour] and [help] and [What's This Place All About?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) --- here you can find out what kinds of questions we take here and what kinds of questions we don't take. As written, your question asks for a list of things, which is a no-no. I'd ask you to focus your query on one particular issue or problem you're facing. You can always ask multiple queries!

Comment: @elemtilas I'm not new here I just don't remember things all that well.

Comment: *would carbon still work*  Would it work *as what* ?  Carbon is carbon and we have limited biological use for pure carbon.  All life as far as we know is based on carbon and mostly carbon-based compounds.  Water is, however, quite different from methane chemically and I'm dubious you could use liquid methane as some sort of water replacement in an organic process.

Comment: @StephenG I presume they're referring to carbon-based life, as opposed to silicon-based life, hydrogen-based life, methane-based life, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Carbon would work better for them than it does for us.**

And carbon works pretty well for us.  But this thing has liquid methane for blood - all the carbon it needs.  At the temperature where methane is liquid, butane and all the larger hydrocarbons are solid.  You could just hook together some of the methane you are using as blood and make solid things to build your body.

[image: hydrocarbon phase change temps]

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/hydrocarbon-boiling-melting-flash-autoignition-point-density-gravity-molweight-d_1966.html

If you want to get into the weeds, everything in your methane blood would need to be hydrophobic if it were going to dissolve.  Maybe this thing could breathe hydrogen - it would still be a gas, it dissolves in hydrocarbons and you need it for alkane chemistry.

Supercold biology is interesting to think about but it can stay carbon based.